# Rendering text in an image in Java

Tags: java, image-processing, java-2d

Are there any nice libraries to render text in an image for Java?

Java has a 2d text library, http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/text/index.html but not sure if theres a better library to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. Java2D is a fairly rich environment for text, as seen in the `Fonts` tab of the demo, located in the `demo/jfc/Java2D` folder of the [Demos and Samples](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html); source code for the font demos may be found in the enclosed `src.zip`. Building on this foundation, I've had good results using the text utilities in [`JCommon`](http://www.jfree.org/jcommon/), now part of [`JFreeChart 1.5`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/). As you are annotating images, a basic example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658663/230513), and you may want to look into using [`AlphaComposite`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html), also previewed in the [Java2D demo](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Here's a method to draw text on an image:

```
public void displayText(BufferedImage image, String text, Font font, int x, int y){
   Graphics2d g = image.createGraphics();
   g.setFont(font);
   g.drawString(text, x, y);
   g.dispose();
}
```