# Using Graphics2D to overlay text on a BufferedImage and return a BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage, graphics2d

*I have checked similarly named questions, but they don't answer this use case.*

Basically, I was to overlay some text (text) at a given coordinate (x,y) I have the below function in a package;

```
protected BufferedImage Process2(BufferedImage image){
    Graphics2D gO = image.createGraphics();
    gO.setColor(Color.red);
    gO.setFont(new Font( "SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 12 ));
    gO.drawString(this.text, this.x, this.y);
    System.err.println(this.text+this.x+this.y);
    return image;
}
```

I feel like im missing something patently obvious; every reference to Graphics2D I can find is dealing with either games or writing directly to a file but I just want a BufferedImage returned. with the overlay 'rendered'

In the current code, the image appears out the end unchanged.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to modify an image file? What you do should work but you're only modifying an in memory representation of the image.

Comment: Also, are you sure that x and y are inside the image? Try to paint a square at coords (0,0) for a first test

Comment: As an aside, this is one time it's appropriate to call `dispose()` on the `Graphics2D` instance.

Comment: @Guillaume no, its a pre-processed BufferedImage, no file-connection atall.
Basically, I have an image source, and I have a completely separate input to define where x,y are, and the text, so i literally want to slap that text at those coords ontop of the buffered image

Comment: @trashgod I promise I'll clean it up once it works :D

Comment: Your text drawing code works fine for me. I think the issue is outside the `Process2` method.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The method [`drawString()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) uses *x* and *y* for the leftmost character's [baseline](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html). Numbers typically have no descenders; if the same is true of `text`, a string drawn at position (0,0) will be rendered entirely outside the image. See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163544/re-paint-problem-on-translucent-frame-panel-component/2166500#2166500).

Addendum: You may be having trouble with an incompatible color model in your image. One simple expedient is to render the image and then modify it *in situ*.

[image: Hello]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658663
 */
public class TextOverlay extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public TextOverlay() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new URL(
                "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        image = process(image);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    }

    private BufferedImage process(BufferedImage old) {
        int w = old.getWidth() / 3;
        int h = old.getHeight() / 3;
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(
            w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(old, 0, 0, w, h, this);
        g2d.setPaint(Color.red);
        g2d.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        String s = "Hello, world!";
        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        int x = img.getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(s) - 5;
        int y = fm.getHeight();
        g2d.drawString(s, x, y);
        g2d.dispose();
        return img;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

    private static void create() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new TextOverlay());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                create();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Well for my tests I'm using x = image.getHeight()/2 and likewise for y, so I dont think that that is the issue, but thanks!

Comment: Any chance you're calling `paintComponent()` with the old image instead of the new?

Comment: I'm not using any JComponents so no, no paintComponents; but if im missing something fundamental, please slap me with it, I am not a GUI coder and have very little knowledge of dealing with graphics in Java so this could be completely the wrong approach

Comment: Pulled out the relevent bit of code, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Works great, but needs some fix if running on Amazon Linux on EC2. See http://brandon.fuller.name/archives/2011/09/12/00.05.15/ for details.