# Image saved in JavaFX as jpg is pink toned

Tags: image, save, png, javafx, jpeg

I want to save an Image from my ImageView to files with different resolutions. Doing it as .png results as expected. As for .jpg - I get all files pink toned.

[image: should be blue]

Where is the trick? Here is the code:

```
Object[] imagesFromFotoListView = ta.myFotoListView.getItems().toArray();
new File(localDir).mkdirs();
for (int i = 0; i < imagesFromFotoListView.length; i++) {
    new File(localDir + "/" + i).mkdirs(); 
    final ImageView iv = new ImageView((Image) imagesFromFotoListView[i]);
    ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(iv.snapshot(null, null), null), "jpg", new File(localModelFotoDir + "/" + i + "/large.jpg")); // JPG THAT FAILS PINK.
    BufferedImage bi = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(iv.snapshot(null, null), null);
    int resolution[] = new int[]{500, 250, 75};
    for (int j = 0; j < resolution.length; j++) {
        BufferedImage resizedBImage;
        if (bi.getWidth() == bi.getHeight()) {
            resizedBImage = resizeBufferedImage(bi, Scalr.Method.ULTRA_QUALITY, Scalr.Mode.AUTOMATIC, resolution[j], resolution[j]);
        } else if (bi.getWidth() > bi.getHeight()) {
            resizedBImage = resizeBufferedImage(bi, Scalr.Method.ULTRA_QUALITY, Scalr.Mode.AUTOMATIC, resolution[j], (int) ((double) resolution[j] * bi.getHeight() / bi.getWidth()));
        } else {
            resizedBImage = resizeBufferedImage(bi, Scalr.Method.ULTRA_QUALITY, Scalr.Mode.AUTOMATIC, (int) ((double) resolution[j] * bi.getWidth() / bi.getHeight()), resolution[j]);
        }
        Image resizedI = (Image) SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(resizedBImage, null);
        ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage((Image) SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(resizedBImage, null), null), "png", new File(localModelFotoDir + "/" + i + "/" + resolution[j] + ".png")); // PNG THAT GOES WELL
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found a solution on Oracle forums. As widely discussed, the **problem is in alpha-channel** that needs to be excluded from the source image, targeted for `.jpg` save. I also rearranged my code to make it shorter. The workaround is:

```
// Get buffered image:
BufferedImage image = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(myJavaFXImage, null); 

// Remove alpha-channel from buffered image:
BufferedImage imageRGB = new BufferedImage(
    image.getWidth(), 
    image.getHeight(), 
    BufferedImage.OPAQUE); 

Graphics2D graphics = imageRGB.createGraphics();

graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

ImageIO.write(imageRGB, "jpg", new File("/mydir/foto.jpg"));

graphics.dispose();
```

Fixed in Java 8: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8114609

Answer (score 1):

*Update JavaFX 17*

I tried this again with JavaFX 17, and unless I used the workaround from the [top-rated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19605733/1155209), I was no longer able to get the image saved.  In my case it would just output a 0 length file, not even the ugly pink files of when it was broken before.

*Update*

This issue was fixed for Java 8:

[JDK-8114609 Incorrect display of JPEG images](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8114609)

---

It looks like you are encountering existing bugs in the ImageIO or JavaFX Image processing libraries.

- [RT-14647 Incorrect display of JPEG images](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-14647)

You might wish to try some of the workarounds suggested in the StackOverflow questions below and see if any of them fix the issue for you:

- [Issue using ImageIO.write jpg file: pink background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386446/problem-using-imageio-write-jpg-file)
- [Java 1.5.0_16 corrupted colours when saving jpg image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753741/java-1-5-0-16-corrupted-colours-when-saving-jpg-image)

Comment: The first link is not public, it requires authentication.

Comment: Yes leonbloy, but [anybody can sign up by clicking the Sign Up link on the authentication page](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-14647) and then view all issues in the JavaFX issue tracker.

Comment: I noticed your [pngj](https://code.google.com/p/pngj/) library leonbloy, perhaps you can [help Oracle fix this stuff](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Main), they certainly [would like help](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Owners+Wanted) with image processing.  Contact the [openjfx-dev mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev) if interested.