# Convert Shape object to Image object in Java

Tags: java, image, shapes

How do I convert a Shape object like Rectangle2D.Double to an Image object?

This way I can use a Shape object for a mousecursor replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Do [`draw(shape)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw%28java.awt.Shape%29) in a `BufferedImage`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658663).

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to create an image object which contains the right pixels at the right locations.

One way would be something like this:

```
public Image makeImage(Shape s) {
    Rectangle r = s.getBounds();
    Image image = new BufferedImage(r.width, r.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
    Graphics2D gr = image.createGraphics();
    // move the shape in the region of the image
    gr.translate(-r.x, -r.y);
    gr.draw(s);
    gr.dispose();
    return image;
}
```

You may want to use another color model, though, to have your shape show up with transparent background, instead of black-on-white or otherwise around.