# How to convert filled Polygon Shape into an image

Tags: java

I have an irregular shape object (Polygon) and wish to convert it to an Image.  The polygon is filled with a gradient. I have an idea on how to do this with rectangular shape objects, but not with Polygons as I can't get the boundaries of the polygon.

I was looking at the solution in this other thread, but it won't work for a polygon shape:
[Convert Shape object to Image object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449633/convert-shape-object-to-image-object-in-java)

Basically, I've a class that creates random terrain as a Polygon shape (for a 'Tanks'/'Castles' type game), but need to convert it to an image for pixel processing.

Any ideas or suggestions?  Sorry if it's an easy question...I'm still very new to Java.

Comment: Is `Polygon` something you've written or from a library?

Comment: better should be moving with prepared images

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear.  Polygon is a java.awt.Polygon.

Answer (score 0):

`"I was looking at the solution in this other thread, but it won't work for a polygon shape: ..."`

Why doesn't Polygon work? It implements the java.awt.Shape interface, which contains all the methods necessary for other objects (the Image) to be able to draw it successfully.

The [Shape#getPathIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#getPathIterator%28java.awt.geom.AffineTransform%29) method is the main method used in determining how to draw Shapes, and Polygon definitally implements it.