# ImageIO.createImageInputStream is returning null, how come?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

This used to work and now it isn't working.  I didn't change the portion where the Image is suppose to stream so I don't know why this isn't working.  Here's a snippet of my code:

```
File f = new File(filepath);
applicantImage=new ImageDetail(filepath);

Iterator<ImageReader> readers =
     ImageIO.getImageReadersBySuffix(applicantImage.getFile_extension());
ImageReader reader = readers.next();

ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(f);
```

`filepath` is the absolute filepath to the image and the image is confirmed to be at that location on the server.  Everything works all fine and dandy until it gets to `ImageIO.createImageInputStream(f)`.  It is returning `null` now.  I read javadoc that it takes in a File.  So why is it returning a `null` now?  Anyone know?  None of the codes posted above were changed in my editing so I don't understand why it worked before the change and why it doesn't work now.  Any help is much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: The `File` instance you are passing in could be causing this. See if `f.exists()` returns `true` just to make sure.

Answer (score 5):

Try using an `InputStream` constructed with the `File`.

```
ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
```

Here's a related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688104/why-does-imagereader-return-incorrect-bufferedimage/5688617#5688617).

Addendum: Looking closer at [`ImageIO.createImageInputStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#createImageInputStream%28java.lang.Object%29), it *does* say that a `File` is permitted. Indeed, your original code works on my platform (Mac OS X), leading me to speculate that the `null` result may be peculiar to your platform's [`ImageInputStreamSpi`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/spi/ImageInputStreamSpi.html) implementation. For a non-existent `File f`,

```
ImageIO.createImageInputStream(f);
```

I get a reasonable exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input not set!
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif.GIFImageReader.read(GIFImageReader.java:784)
    at javax.imageio.ImageReader.read(ImageReader.java:923)
    at cli.GifBounds.search(GifBounds.java:22)
    at cli.GifBounds.main(GifBounds.java:14)
```

Comment: Also consider wrapping `FileInputStream ` with `BufferedInputStream`.

Comment: +1 - if `f` does not exist or can't be read, then you should get an exception to say so.  (None of this "return null and don't tell the application why" nonsense.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the input before:

```
reader.setInput(iis);
dimension = new Dimension(reader.getWidth(0), reader.getHeight(0));
System.out.print(dimension);
```