# Writing an animated gif from BufferedImages

Tags: java, bufferedimage, animated-gif

I have a program that loads a spritesheet, creates BufferedImages of each frame on the sheet, and writes it to an animated gif. Using the class provided by Elliot Kroo on [Creating animated GIF with ImageIO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777947/creating-animated-gif-with-imageio), I was able to successfully output a file. However, the gif doesn't animate quite right. The sheet I provided was a .png with a transparent background, so every subsequent frame is just put on top of the last frames, with differences showing through the transparent background ([Example](http://i55.tinypic.com/2qvawdx.gif)). Here's the code that uses the gif writer:

```
ImageOutputStream output = new FileImageOutputStream(new File(savePath));
GifSequenceWriter writer = new GifSequenceWriter(output, data[0].getType(), delay, true);
for(BufferedImage bi:data)
{
    writer.writeToSequence(bi);
}
writer.close();
output.close();
```

Where data is an array of each frame as a BufferedImage (which I have also checked, and don't seem to be the problem). Is this a limitation of .gifs or the Java ImageWriters? Or can I edit a setting somewhere to prevent this? I'd rather not put a background if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `data` is an array of [`BufferedImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_ARGB), the `imageType` parameter to the [`GifSequenceWriter`](http://elliot.kroo.net/software/java/GifSequenceWriter/GifSequenceWriter.java) constructor would likely be `TYPE_INT_ARGB` for data read from a `.png` file. I would expect `transparentColorFlag` to be `true`, but you'd have to determine the `transparentColorIndex` empirically.

```
graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("transparentColorFlag", "TRUE");
graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("transparentColorIndex", ???);
```

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688104/why-does-imagereader-return-incorrect-bufferedimage/5688617#5688617).

Comment: Ah. Is there no way to edit the behavior of the gifwriter to not use the optimized frames? Also, the color for the transparent background seemed to be black(0,0,0), but passing 0 for the transparentColorIndex doesn't seem to affect anything(not even the normal black goes away).

Comment: Not as far as I know. Kroo's code seems to assume opaque images. A `.gif` lacks an alpha channel; it only has a color index meant to be interpreted as transparent. If you need to preserve the `.png` transparency, you might try this [`AnimatedGifEncoder`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/AnimatedGifEncoder.htm).

Comment: Do you know what I should assign the attribute transparentColorIndex? It doesn't seem to be an int with ARGB color.

Comment: Right, `transparentColorIndex` isn't a color; it's an index in the `.gif color table; it would be whatever color your encoder chooses, e.g. `findClosest()`. Note that `GifSequenceWriter` uses the `ImageIO` encoder, while `AnimatedGifEncoder` does its own encoding.

Comment: `findClosest()` is a method of [`AnimatedGifEncoder`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/AnimatedGifEncoder.htm), which does its own encoding. I doesn't use the `ImageIO` encoder.