# How can I make a gif out of a .png containing several frames?

Tags: java, png, gif, frames

I need to automatically convert to an animated .gif a .png file containing several frames. I know how many frames does each file contain. All images have transparency, but no alpha channel. Frames are sorted vertically, although I guess that won't make any difference. Since I don't have enough reputation it seems I can't upload pics, but you can figure.

Is there any library I can use? I'm pretty new to Java and I'm stuck with this.

Thanks.

Comment: To whomever downvoted this, I think it's a valid question. All najko needs is to know where to start. He's not asking us to do his homework or anything like that.

Comment: @Renan the problem looks like OP hasn't done enough research on his/her own about this. Voting to close.

Comment: Sorry about it, I just feel rushed and want to start working on it as soon as possible. I admit I did little research. However I've found from an old thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967809/writing-an-animated-gif-from-bufferedimages?lq=1 a class that might solve my problem. It's the one suggested by trashgod, down at the comments. I'll look into it and try to do it by myself.

Comment: After all I managed to get the GIFs properly! Now all I need to know is: what Object Color(r,g,b,a) values equal full alpha transparency? If I set it to Color(0,0,0,0) it works properly for most cases but sometimes sets black color transparent too. Is there any way to avoid this?
I can give more details if needed, just ask.

Answer (score 1):

What you actually need to do is to crop the big PNG into several small images (frames), and then build the animated GIF.

Meet [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/).