# Mirroring animated gif on load in Java - ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, animation, awt, imageicon

So I have an animated gif that I load into an ImageIcon like this:

```
Image image = new ImageIcon("image.gif").getImage();
```

and I can draw it using this:

```
g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
```

I know that I can mirror it on the fly using AffineTransform, but I need to be able to mirror it horizontally after loading, so that I can draw the mirrored one instead if needed without the overhead of transforming it every time it gets redrawn. Is there a way to do this using swing/awt?

A library that could do this would also be a huge help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, as you have pointed out, is the fact the gif's are animated.

Unless you desperately want to take over the job of having to render each frame yourself, the only choice you have is to use an `AffineTransform` with in the paint method.

Generally speaking, you shouldn't see a significant difference (in rendering).

If you are really desperate, you could simply pre-render the gif externally and provide a mirrored version

**Updated with a "kind of" working example**

This is a combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967809/writing-an-animated-gif-from-bufferedimages) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777947/creating-animated-gif-with-imageio) answers, using [this](http://elliot.kroo.net/software/java/GifSequenceWriter/) GIF writer.

Basically what this example does is it reads an original gif image, mirrors it frame by frame, and writes back out to a mirrored file.

It then loads both the original and mirrored files back in as `ImageIcon`s, mostly because I'm not really up to re-inventing the wheel for display animated gifs.  Yes, you could do it and everything you would need is provided within..

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.imageio.IIOException;
import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata;
import javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadataNode;
import javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class MirrorImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MirrorImage();
    }

    public MirrorImage() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private ImageIcon orig;
        private ImageIcon mirror;

        public TestPane() {
            mirror(new File("java_animated.gif"), new File("Mirror.gif"));
            orig = new ImageIcon("java_animated.gif");
            mirror = new ImageIcon("Mirror.gif");
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return mirror == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(orig.getIconWidth(), orig.getIconHeight() * 2);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (orig != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int x = (getWidth() - orig.getIconWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - (orig.getIconHeight() * 2)) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(orig.getImage(), x, y, this);

//                AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
//                at.setToScale(1, -1);
//                at.translate(0, -mirror.getIconHeight());
//                g2d.setTransform(at);
                g2d.drawImage(mirror.getImage(), x, y + mirror.getIconHeight(), this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void mirror(File source, File dest) {

        List<BufferedImage> images = new ArrayList<>(25);
        List<Integer> delays = new ArrayList<>(25);
        int delay = 0;

        ImageOutputStream output = null;
        GifSequenceWriter writer = null;

        try {

            String[] imageatt = new String[]{
                "imageLeftPosition",
                "imageTopPosition",
                "imageWidth",
                "imageHeight"
            };

            ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("gif").next();
            ImageInputStream ciis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(source);
            reader.setInput(ciis, false);
            int noi = reader.getNumImages(true);
            BufferedImage master = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < noi; i++) {

                BufferedImage image = reader.read(i);
                IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(i);

                Node tree = metadata.getAsTree("javax_imageio_gif_image_1.0");
                NodeList children = tree.getChildNodes();
                for (int j = 0; j < children.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node nodeItem = children.item(j);
                    System.out.println(nodeItem.getNodeName());
                    if (nodeItem.getNodeName().equals("ImageDescriptor")) {
                        Map<String, Integer> imageAttr = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                        NamedNodeMap attr = nodeItem.getAttributes();
//                        for (int index = 0; index < attr.getLength(); index++) {
//                            Node node = attr.item(index);
//                            System.out.println("----> " + node.getNodeName() + "=" + node.getNodeValue());
//                        }
                        for (int k = 0; k < imageatt.length; k++) {
                            Node attnode = attr.getNamedItem(imageatt[k]);
                            imageAttr.put(imageatt[k], Integer.valueOf(attnode.getNodeValue()));
                        }

                        if (master == null) {
                            master = new BufferedImage(imageAttr.get("imageWidth"), imageAttr.get("imageHeight"), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                        }

                        Graphics2D g2d = master.createGraphics();
                        g2d.drawImage(image, imageAttr.get("imageLeftPosition"), imageAttr.get("imageTopPosition"), null);
                        g2d.dispose();

                        BufferedImage frame = mirror(copyImage(master));
                        ImageIO.write(frame, "png", new File("img" + i + ".png"));
                        images.add(frame);

                    } else if (nodeItem.getNodeName().equals("GraphicControlExtension")) {
                        NamedNodeMap attr = nodeItem.getAttributes();
                        Node delayNode = attr.getNamedItem("delayTime");
                        if (delayNode != null) {
                            delay = Math.max(delay, Integer.valueOf(delayNode.getNodeValue()));
                            delays.add(delay);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            output = new FileImageOutputStream(dest);
            writer = new GifSequenceWriter(output, images.get(0).getType(), delay * 10, true);

            for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
                BufferedImage nextImage = images.get(i);
                writer.writeToSequence(nextImage);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static BufferedImage mirror(BufferedImage img) {

        BufferedImage mirror = createCompatibleImage(img);
        Graphics2D g2d = mirror.createGraphics();
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.setToScale(1, -1);
        at.translate(0, -img.getHeight());
        g2d.setTransform(at);
        g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();

        return mirror;

    }

    public static BufferedImage copyImage(BufferedImage img) {
        int width = img.getWidth();
        int height = img.getHeight();

        BufferedImage newImage = createCompatibleImage(img);
        Graphics graphics = newImage.createGraphics();

        int x = (width - img.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y = (height - img.getHeight()) / 2;

        graphics.drawImage(img, x, y, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), null);
        graphics.dispose();

        return newImage;
    }

    public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(BufferedImage image) {
        return getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image.getTransparency());
    }

    public static GraphicsConfiguration getGraphicsConfiguration() {
        return GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
    }

    public static class GifSequenceWriter {

        protected ImageWriter gifWriter;
        protected ImageWriteParam imageWriteParam;
        protected IIOMetadata imageMetaData;

        /**
         * Creates a new GifSequenceWriter
         *
         * @param outputStream the ImageOutputStream to be written to
         * @param imageType one of the imageTypes specified in BufferedImage
         * @param timeBetweenFramesMS the time between frames in miliseconds
         * @param loopContinuously wether the gif should loop repeatedly
         * @throws IIOException if no gif ImageWriters are found
         *
         * @author Elliot Kroo (elliot[at]kroo[dot]net)
         */
        public GifSequenceWriter(
                ImageOutputStream outputStream,
                int imageType,
                int timeBetweenFramesMS,
                boolean loopContinuously) throws IIOException, IOException {
            // my method to create a writer
            gifWriter = getWriter();
            imageWriteParam = gifWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
            ImageTypeSpecifier imageTypeSpecifier
                    = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(imageType);

            imageMetaData
                    = gifWriter.getDefaultImageMetadata(imageTypeSpecifier,
                    imageWriteParam);

            String metaFormatName = imageMetaData.getNativeMetadataFormatName();

            IIOMetadataNode root = (IIOMetadataNode) imageMetaData.getAsTree(metaFormatName);

            IIOMetadataNode graphicsControlExtensionNode = getNode(
                    root,
                    "GraphicControlExtension");

            graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("disposalMethod", "none");
            graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("userInputFlag", "FALSE");
            graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute(
                    "transparentColorFlag",
                    "FALSE");
            graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute(
                    "delayTime",
                    Integer.toString(timeBetweenFramesMS / 10));
            graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute(
                    "transparentColorIndex",
                    "0");

            IIOMetadataNode commentsNode = getNode(root, "CommentExtensions");
            commentsNode.setAttribute("CommentExtension", "Created by MAH");

            IIOMetadataNode appEntensionsNode = getNode(
                    root,
                    "ApplicationExtensions");

            IIOMetadataNode child = new IIOMetadataNode("ApplicationExtension");

            child.setAttribute("applicationID", "NETSCAPE");
            child.setAttribute("authenticationCode", "2.0");

            int loop = loopContinuously ? 0 : 1;

            child.setUserObject(new byte[]{0x1, (byte) (loop & 0xFF), (byte) ((loop >> 8) & 0xFF)});
            appEntensionsNode.appendChild(child);

            imageMetaData.setFromTree(metaFormatName, root);

            gifWriter.setOutput(outputStream);

            gifWriter.prepareWriteSequence(null);
        }

        public void writeToSequence(RenderedImage img) throws IOException {
            gifWriter.writeToSequence(
                    new IIOImage(
                    img,
                    null,
                    imageMetaData),
                    imageWriteParam);
        }

        /**
         * Close this GifSequenceWriter object. This does not close the underlying
         * stream, just finishes off the GIF.
         */
        public void close() throws IOException {
            gifWriter.endWriteSequence();
        }

        /**
         * Returns the first available GIF ImageWriter using
         * ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("gif").
         *
         * @return a GIF ImageWriter object
         * @throws IIOException if no GIF image writers are returned
         */
        private static ImageWriter getWriter() throws IIOException {
            Iterator<ImageWriter> iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("gif");
            if (!iter.hasNext()) {
                throw new IIOException("No GIF Image Writers Exist");
            } else {
                return iter.next();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns an existing child node, or creates and returns a new child node
         * (if the requested node does not exist).
         *
         * @param rootNode the <tt>IIOMetadataNode</tt> to search for the child
         * node.
         * @param nodeName the name of the child node.
         *
         * @return the child node, if found or a new node created with the given
         * name.
         */
        private static IIOMetadataNode getNode(
                IIOMetadataNode rootNode,
                String nodeName) {
            int nNodes = rootNode.getLength();
            for (int i = 0; i < nNodes; i++) {
                if (rootNode.item(i).getNodeName().compareToIgnoreCase(nodeName)
                        == 0) {
                    return ((IIOMetadataNode) rootNode.item(i));
                }
            }
            IIOMetadataNode node = new IIOMetadataNode(nodeName);
            rootNode.appendChild(node);
            return (node);
        }
    }
}
```

**Caveats**

The Gif writer currently only works with fixed rate gifs.  It should be possible to change this, but I didn't have the time.

Basically, as I understand it, you would need to pass a "frame" delay to the `writeToSquence` method.  Within this method you would need to construct an appropriate `IIOMetadata` with all the required properties, plus your frame delay...

**Updated after playing with original gif**

The GIF I was playing with was optimised.  That is, each frame "added" to the animation, rather then being a brand new frame.  Yours is the other way round.  Each frame is an entire image.

Now, there are probably lots of ways you could check for this, but right now, I can't be bothered...

Instead...in the `mirror(File, File)` method, I changed it so that rather then using a single "master" image, each frame creates a new `BufferedImage`

```
BufferedImage frame = new BufferedImage(imageAttr.get("imageWidth"), imageAttr.get("imageHeight"), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

Graphics2D g2d = frame.createGraphics();
g2d.drawImage(image, imageAttr.get("imageLeftPosition"), imageAttr.get("imageTopPosition"), null);
g2d.dispose();

frame = mirror(frame);
ImageIO.write(frame, "png", new File("img" + i + ".png"));
images.add(frame);
```

I also updated the `GifSequenceWriter` to set the meta data to more closely match the original as well...

```
graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("disposalMethod", "restoreToBackgroundColor");
graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("userInputFlag", "FALSE");
graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute(
        "transparentColorFlag",
        "TRUE");
```

[image][image]

Comment: yes, obviously I will keep track of two instances. What I'm asking is how to mirror the gif on loading, so that I don't have to mirror it every time it's drawn.

Comment: it says in the title and in the post that it's animated, yes

Comment: Okay, you have a problem

Comment: Some times you need to go around the bush to find the easter egg ;)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. The code you give generates the individual frames of the gif correctly, but something seems to be wrong with GifWriter because the gif it produces has the later images in the animation simply drawn over the earlier ones instead of in their own frame, and it results in the frames all drawn over top of each other towards the end of the gif.

Comment: I had to do that to get my image to work (and it was the way that the original extraction code actually worked).  Instead of using the `master` image, you could generate each frame as a new `BufferedImage`.  I would take the size of the first frame as the base's for all the others.  There might be an "optimised" flag some where which tells you if the frames are optimised or not...

Comment: Are you able to post your original gif so I can compare the meta-data

Comment: I had already tried creating a new BufferedImage for master each iteration, no luck. I don't think its a problem with generating the frames, because the .png files all look correct

Comment: I've updated some of the properties and used a new `BufferedImage` for each frame :P

Comment: Updating the metadata writing seems to have fixed it! Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

> ..overhead of transforming it every time..

That overhead is just about 0.  But if you don't want to use `AffineTransform` simply change the x,y in a loop.

See also  [Show an animated BG in Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10836832/418556) for more tips.

### Note

This:

```
g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
```

Should be:

```
g.drawImage(image, x, y, this); // containers are typically an ImageObserver!
```

Answer (score 0):

For non-animated images, you can create a mirrored image.

```
// Width and height
int w = image.getWidth(null);
int h = image.getHeight(null);

// Create a new BufferedImage
BufferedImage mirror = new BufferedImage(w, h);

// Draw the image flipping it horizontally
Graphics2D g = mirror.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, w, h, w, 0, 0, h, null);

// Dispose the graphics.
g.dispose();
```

You can then use `mirror` which is already mirrored horizontally.

Comment: the problem is it's an animated gif, so if I do that, mirror will contain one frame of the animation mirrored and that's it