# resizing animated GIF while keeping it's animation using java

Tags: java, animation, gif

i am using Graphics2D in java to resize images, it works perfect with jpg,png and other formats.
my problem is the animated GIF images, after re-sizing the animation is gone!

here is the method am using:

```
    private BufferedImage doResize(int newWidth, int newHeight, double scaleX,
        double scaleY, BufferedImage source) {

    GraphicsConfiguration gc = getDefaultConfiguration();
    BufferedImage result = gc.createCompatibleImage(newWidth, newHeight, source.getColorModel().getTransparency());
    Graphics2D g2d = null;

    try {
        g2d = result.createGraphics();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
        g2d.drawImage(source, 0, 0, null);
    } finally {
        if (g2d != null) {
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

so, any clues how can i keep on the animated gif after re-sizing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

So I know this is old but I found a solution, I am using Java 8 not sure if it will work with other versions.

```
    ImageIcon image = ? (whatever/wherever your gif is)
    int width = 100;
    int height = 100;
    image.setImage(image.getImage().getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
```

you can change SCALE_DEFAULT to the ones listed here except for SCALE_SMOOTH and SCALE_AREA_AVREAGING didn't work for me, it was blank
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html

Comment: This is the method I use. SCALE_SMOOTH and SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING are the same algorithm under the covers, and I can confirm that I get a blank image output if I feed it an animated GIF. Best results from SCALE_DEFAULT in that case.

For other images, SCALE_SMOOTH produces somewhat nicer results.

Comment: Excellent advice, this really works. Of course smoothing would be even more desirable but this is ok to get some results quickly.

Answer (score 8):

I found two sources which when combined can be used to resize the image while keeping the animation.

On this question (
[Convert each animated GIF frame to a separate BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933893/convert-animated-gif-frames-to-separate-bufferedimages-java) ) look for the answer by Alex Orzechowski. His code takes a gif file and converts it to an array of ImageFrames (which is a class he made which wraps a BufferedImage). Then look at this code which converts a sequence of BufferedImages to a gif file
( http://elliot.kroo.net/software/java/GifSequenceWriter/ ).

As you could probably guess, all you need to do is upload the gif, use Alex's code to convert it to an array of ImageFiles/BufferedImages, use your Graphics2D code to resize each frame (you'll need to add a setImage method to Alex's ImageFrame class), then use Elliot's code to convert the array to a gif! Here is what mine looks like:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
  try {
     File imageFile = new File( "InputFile" );
     FileInputStream fiStream = new FileInputStream( imageFile );

     ImageFrame[] frames = readGif( fiStream );
     for( int i = 0; i < frames.length; i++ ){
        //code to resize the image
        BufferedImage image = ImageUtilities.resizeImage( frames[ i ].getImage(), newWidth, newHeight);
        frames[ i ].setImage( image );
   }

     ImageOutputStream output =
       new FileImageOutputStream( new File( "OutputFile" ) );

     GifSequenceWriter writer =
       new GifSequenceWriter( output, frames[0].getImage().getType(), frames[0].getDelay(), true );

     writer.writeToSequence( frames[0].getImage() );
     for ( int i = 1; i < frames.length; i++ ) {
        BufferedImage nextImage = frames[i].getImage();
        writer.writeToSequence( nextImage );
     }

     writer.close();
     output.close();
  }
  catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
     System.out.println( "File not found" );
  }
  catch ( IOException e ) {
     System.out.println( "IO Exception" );
  }
}
```

This code, however, does not account for gif images with different amount of time elapsing between frames.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. Totally solved it and I can resize gifs and keep the animation now. Only note is you should multiply frames[0].getDelay() by 10 because inside GifSequenceWriter it divides by 10 (to adjust from milliseconds)

Comment: It work well but takes around 200MB for gif of size 1MB and 222 frames. is there any why to reduce memory usage??

Comment: Thank yout for the Hint with the Sequence!

Comment: elliot site is down. `GifSequenceWriter` code could be found here: https://github.com/Deep-Symmetry/wayang/blob/main/src/main/java/org/deepsymmetry/GifSequenceWriter.java (or use web archive)

Answer (score 1):

Jonny March's solution did not work for me because it processes and outputs only the first image of GIF file.

Here is my solution, it keeps the animation while resizing.

```
File f = new File("path of your animated gif");
URL img = f.toURL();
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
//You have to convert it to URL because ImageIO just ruins the animation

int width = 100;
int height = 100;
icon.setImage(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(width, height,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
```

Answer (score 0):

BufferedImage origBuffImg = ImageIO.read(orignalImage);
int type = origBuffImg.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : origBuffImg.getType();

```
          BufferedImage resizedBuffImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, type);
          Graphics2D g = resizedBuffImg.createGraphics();
          g.drawImage(origBuffImg, 0, 0, width, height, null);
          g.dispose();
         
          String newFile = orignalImage.getAbsolutePath().substring(0,orignalImage.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("."))+"_"+width+"x"+height+"."+extension;
          ImageIO.write(resizedBuffImg, extension, new File(newFile));
         
          System.out.println("File created : "+newFile);
```

Comment: please do write some explanation with your code and do intent your code properly.