# Java: how to set .gif to the same size as the frame

Tags: java, swing

so I was messing around with a GUI and I wanted to challenge myself to display a gif. I ended up being able to do it but now I can't make the gif fit the entire frame instead of just a portion. I made the frame so you can't change the size and to be the same size as the monitor.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

public class gif {
public static void main (String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

    URL url = new URL("http://stream1.gifsoup.com/view2/1605810/paranoid-android-o.gif");
    Icon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    label.setSize(screenSize);
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);
    frame.setTitle("what?");
    frame.setSize(screenSize);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm aware it's worded very poorly, any edits would be much appreciated

Comment: I think you need to use the java Image package and rescale your image so it fits in the frame dimension.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634293/animating-multiple-images-using-java/19638875#19638875

Comment: You might try to use HTML to load the image and specify the width & height in terms of % rather than pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> now I can't make the gif fit the entire frame instead of just a portion

The JLabel will size itself based upon the ImageIcon inside. You can resize the image to the desired scale. For example:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
Image i2 = image.getScaledInstance(screenSize.width, screenSize.height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(i2));
....
```

This being said, the input Image is an gif, so if animation exists in the Image you will have to take that into consideration. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392227/resizing-animated-gif-while-keeping-its-animation-using-java) for resizing animated gifs.

Comment: I realize i could change it easily if it weren't animated, the problem with all the tutorials on how to do this already is i don't understand the syntax since they use a different method of putting the gif onto the frame