# .getScaledInstance working with animated GIFs

Tags: java, swing, jframe, gif, animated-gif

I have scaled images easily with the `.getScaledInstance` when importing them like so:

```
player_sprite = a_1.getImage().getScaledInstance(150, 150, 100);
```

But the same cannot be said about scaling animated GIFs as when I do the same method of scaling a GIF it causes issues when displaying it. When using `g.drawImage` it only draws the first frame then disappears.

Here is the full code for importing the GIF that I use and below will be an example of how I display the animated GIF onto the `JFrame`:

Importing it:

```
    ImageIcon a_1 = new ImageIcon(FrontHand.class.getResource("/Sprites/character_move_down.gif"));
    move_player_down = a_1.getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 100, 100);
```

Displaying it:

```
    g.drawImage(move_player_down, 100, 100, this);
```

Is there another simple method I could use for increasing the size of the animated GIF or is there a simple fix for this issue.

Comment: GIF's should scale no differently from other file formats, unless you're talking specifically about *animated* GIF's. If so, you might want to put this critical information in your question.

Comment: 1. Passing in `100` as the last parameter to `getScaledInstance` does not make sense. 2. Do you *really* need the scaled *instance*? Can't you just draw it larger (with the appropriate `drawImage` call, or maybe a transformed `Graphics2D`? 3. Do you really need to scale it *in your program*? Can't you use an external tool to create the image with the desired size? Obtaining a scaled instance of an animated gif seems to be surprisingly hard. This http://stackoverflow.com/q/9392227/ is basically a duplicate, but the answer looks very fiddly...EDIT @HovercraftFullOfEels *"draws the first frame"*

Comment: didn't know there was a difference will update it :)

Comment: In my situation I cannot recreate the gif to be larger

Comment: @Taka Just a hint: When answering to a comment, using `@` will notify the respective user (as [recently discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335607) )

Comment: @Marco13 okay, will note for next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution while going into scalr, I ended not with scalr but instead found a comment on a scalr thread which using .getscaledinstance is changing the size and then printing with paintIcon and not drawImage like so:

Change in size:

```
ImageIcon a_1 = new ImageIcon(FrontHand.class.getResource("/Sprites/character_move_down.gif"));
a_1.setImage(a_1.getImage().getScaledInstance(150, 150, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
move_player_down = a_1;
```

Painting the icon:

```
move_player_down.paintIcon(this, g, 100, 100);
```

It works like a charm and does not require me to change all my previous code to work around it :)