# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4096 while reading gif file

Tags: java, gif, javax.imageio

I am able to read png file. But getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4096 while reading gif file.

```
byte[] fileData = imageFile.getFileData();
ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData);
RenderedImage image = ImageIO.read(byteArrayInputStream)
```

Exception thrown looks like

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4096
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif.GIFImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
```

what could be the issue and what is the resolution?

Comment: does this happen with every gif you try to read or only with specific gifs

Comment: It almost happened with all the gif's I have.

Comment: Couldn't you simply do `ImageIO.read(imageFile.getInputStream())`?

Comment: Can you provide one of these GIFs?

Comment: @zapl -- tried to read as you mentions. But still getting the same exception.

Comment: You might have either corrupt `.gif` files (e.g. too short / not completely transferred yet or so) or a type of gif that is not understood by `ImageIO`.

Comment: Your code is good. There is something special about your GIF files, they are either corrupt or of a version not supported by the `GIFImageReader`. Could also be a bug in your specific JDK/JRE version. We can't help you anymore if you don't provide a GIF that causes the problem AND state what JDK/JRE you are using.

Comment: Thank You haraldk. I will try with the options you told me. Will reply

Comment: This is clearly a bug of the internal GIFImageReader which never got fixed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Update 3: Solution**

I ended up developing my own GifDecoder and released it as open source under the Apache License 2.0. You can get it from here: https://github.com/DhyanB/Open-Imaging. It does not suffer from the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` issue and delivers decent performance.

Any feedback is highly appreciated. In particular, I'd like to know if it works correctly for all of your images and if you are happy with its speed.

I hope this is helpful to you (:

**Initial answer**

Maybe this bug report is related to or describes the same problem: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7132728.

Quote:

```
FULL PRODUCT VERSION :
java version "1.7.0_02"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)

ADDITIONAL OS VERSION INFORMATION :
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

A DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM :
according to specification
http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt
> There is not a requirement to send a clear code when the string table is full.

However, GIFImageReader requires the clear code when the string table is full.
GIFImageReader violates the specification, clearly.
In the real world, sometimes people finds such high compressed gif image.
so you should fix this bug.

STEPS TO FOLLOW TO REPRODUCE THE PROBLEM :
javac -cp .;PATH_TO_COMMONS_CODEC GIF_OverflowStringList_Test.java
java -cp .;PATH_TO_COMMONS_CODEC GIF_OverflowStringList_Test

EXPECTED VERSUS ACTUAL BEHAVIOR :
EXPECTED -
complete normally. no output
ACTUAL -
ArrayIndexOutOfBounds occurs.

ERROR MESSAGES/STACK TRACES THAT OCCUR :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4096
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif.GIFImageReader.read(GIFImageReader.java:1
075)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1400)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1322)
        at GIF_OverflowStringList_Test.main(GIF_OverflowStringList_Test.java:8)


REPRODUCIBILITY :
This bug can be reproduced always.
```

The bug report also provides code to reproduce the bug.

**Update 1**

And here is an image that causes the bug in my own code:

[image]

**Update 2**

I tried to read the same image using Apache Commons Imaging, which led to the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: AddStringToTable: codes: 4096 code_size: 12
    at org.apache.commons.imaging.common.mylzw.MyLzwDecompressor.addStringToTable(MyLzwDecompressor.java:112)
    at org.apache.commons.imaging.common.mylzw.MyLzwDecompressor.decompress(MyLzwDecompressor.java:168)
    at org.apache.commons.imaging.formats.gif.GifImageParser.readImageDescriptor(GifImageParser.java:388)
    at org.apache.commons.imaging.formats.gif.GifImageParser.readBlocks(GifImageParser.java:251)
    at org.apache.commons.imaging.formats.gif.GifImageParser.readFile(GifImageParser.java:455)
    at org.apache.commons.imaging.formats.gif.GifImageParser.readFile(GifImageParser.java:435)
    at org.apache.commons.imaging.formats.gif.GifImageParser.getBufferedImage(GifImageParser.java:646)
    at org.apache.commons.imaging.Imaging.getBufferedImage(Imaging.java:1378)
    at org.apache.commons.imaging.Imaging.getBufferedImage(Imaging.java:1292)
```

That looks very similar to the problem we have with ImageIO, so I reported the bug at the Apache Commons JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMAGING-130.

Comment: Wow, this is crazy that they haven't gotten it fixed after all this time.

Comment: JDK 1.8.0_45 here... bug still exists :\

Comment: I encountered a similar bug recently. Out of bounds exception occurs on the 11th frame.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thanks for including a test image. This SO answer was linked in IMAGING-130, and another contributor submitted a pull request that has already been merged. This fix will be available in the commons-imaging-1.0-alpha2 release. Thanks! Bruno

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the exact same problem you did, but I had to stick to an ImageIO interface, which no other library did. Apart from Jack's great answer, I simply patched the existing `GIFImageReader` class with a few lines of code, and got it marginally working.

Copy [this link](http://pastebin.com/h58zjT8K) into `PatchedGIFImageReader.java` and use as such:

```
reader = new PatchedGIFImageReader(null);
reader.setInput(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new FileInputStream(files[i])));
int ub = reader.getNumImages(true);
for (int x=0;x<ub;x++) {
    BufferedImage img = reader.read(x);
    //Do whatever with the new img bufferedimage
```

Be sure to change the package name to whatever you're using.

Unfortunately results may vary, as the patch was a 1 minute bugfix that basically just exits the loop if it goes past the buffer. Some gifs it loads fine, others have a few visual artifacts.

Such is life. If anyone knows a better fix instead of mine, please do tell.