# The 11th image is never recognized by the reader

Tags: image, io

I am trying to convert a gif into an Arraylist of buffered images. I had used a piece of code from [Convert each animated GIF frame to a separate BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933893/convert-each-animated-gif-frame-to-a-separate-bufferedimage?noredirect=1&lq=1) before, but it returned buffered images where every pixel was the same exact color. Thus, I decided to use this instead:

```
public ArrayList<BufferedImage> getFrames(File gif) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<BufferedImage> frames = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
        try {
            ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("gif").next();
            ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(gif);
            reader.setInput(stream);
            int count = reader.getNumImages(true);
            System.out.println("count is "+count);
            for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
                System.out.println("index is "+index);
                BufferedImage frame = reader.read(index);
                frames.add(frame);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("An I/O problem has occurred");
        }
        return frames;
}
```

The output indicates that there is an error on the 10th image:

```
count is 70
index is 0
index is 1
index is 2
index is 3
index is 4
index is 5
index is 6
index is 7
index is 8
index is 9
index is 10
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4096
```

I'm wondering: why 10? What happens at the 11th image that causes this problem? How do I fix the error so that I can have all 70 frames?

Here is the rest of the errors (with a stacktrack added in):

```
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif.GIFImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at Pointilismo.getFrames(Pointilismo.java:104)
    at Pointilismo.updateimage(Pointilismo.java:116)
    at Pointilismo.switchimage(Pointilismo.java:135)
    at Pointilismo.actionPerformed(Pointilismo.java:210)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: do you have a stacktrace so you get more information about where exactly the exception is thrown ?

Comment: @Conffusion I've added that and updated to show the rest of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with Image processing but found maybe the cause of your problem:
[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259714/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-4096-while-reading-gif-file)