# how to extract frames of an animated .gif file in android

Tags: android, gif

I want to extract all frames(images) of an animated `.gif` file as `bitmap` or `Drawable` or any common type of image and store all images in an array in android. How i do it? 
please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "frames"? Are you talking about animated gifs?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  Yes i mean is animated gif. and frames is all image that show in animated gif file.

Comment: `android.graphics.Movie`

Comment: @pskink please explain me clearly what i do it? Thanks.

Comment: use `Movie` class for decoding and drawing your animated gif content

Comment: @pskink I have to read 'android.graphics.Movie' documentation in android.com? only read that documentation enough?

Comment: What do you want to do with the frames of an animated gif? Are you just going to show them?

Comment: If you want to display an animated gif in your app, I suggest [googling for it](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+animated+gif&oq=android+animated&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.8734j0j4&client=ms-android-verizon&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#xxri=4).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  I want to get all frames of an animated gif and save that frames in an array and show it manually by next and previous buttons.

Comment: You either need to find a library that will do this or learn about the gif format and write your own.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks.

Comment: so after reading `android.graphics.Movie` documentation, what problems did you get in your code?

Comment: @pskink I don't understand Movie class from this main documantation [android.graphics.Movie](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie.html) it is very summarized!

Comment: what you did not understand? how to create a `Movie` object? how to draw it?

Comment: @pskink How to i get frames after decode my gif file to an **Movie**  object?

Comment: simply draw them

Comment: @pskink how to draw them? draw want canvas? how to i create canvas?

Comment: @pskink draw want canvas? how to i create canvas?

Comment: by calling `new Canvas()` constructor? did you read `android.graphics.Canvas` documentation?

Comment: I know I'm super late to this party, but this stackoverflow thread may help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933893/convert-each-animated-gif-frame-to-a-separate-bufferedimage