# Finish the animation before displaying text

Tags: java, swing, animated-gif

```
ImageIcon v = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Sample1/Image1.gif"));
v.getImage().flush();
jLabel1.setIcon(v);
JLabel2.setText("Sample");
```

How to finish the animation first before changing the text of jLabel2?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Image1.gif` is an [*animated GIF*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format#Animated_GIF), I see two approaches:

- Extract the images from the GIF, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5688617/230513), and display them in a single sequence.
- Play the GIF for a fixed period, then set the label's icon to one constructed from a `BufferedImage` copy of the GIF, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658663/230513).

In either case use [`javax.Swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) as required for timing