# How to get InputStream from ImageReader android

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, file-descriptor, fileinputstream

I was looking at this class : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html

What I want is to get an InputStream from the ImageReader class and get the image data which is being rendering into the current surface. Current Surface means the currently displaying android screen.
I looked at an example inside the AOSP code but it was really tough to understand.
Please it would be really helpful if someone provides me with a nice example of ImageReader class.

Comment: Take look on this thread 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688104/why-does-imagereader-return-incorrect-bufferedimage

Comment: The documentation says use `acquireLatestImage()` method to grab the Image.

Comment: @mohammedmomn Thanks for your response but I need to use android.media.ImageReader

Comment: @DevZer0 But I'm not getting how to set the Surface. I want the image that is being shown in the current screen.

Comment: Can you show some of your code what your doing, do you have a instance of the ImageReader you want to use?

Comment: I wrote some random code using this : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/kitkat-release/tests/tests/hardware/src/android/hardware/camera2/cts/ImageReaderTest.java

Comment: I wrote some random code using this : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/kitkat-release/tests/tests/hardware/src/android/hardware/camera2/cts/ImageReaderTest.java . But I'm not able to get how to get Images from the currently displaying screen in android using ImageReader.

Comment: This is my random code : http://pastebin.com/dQVj74XR

Comment: I found another test regarding ImageReader : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/33286bc/tests/tests/display/src/android/display/cts/VirtualDisplayTest.java
If anyone could help.

Comment: You can refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219799/system-error-capturing-the-output-of-a-mediaprojection-virtual-display-to-an-ima/27638215?noredirect=1#comment43774763_27638215

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to use `ImageReader` to pull data out of an arbitrary `Surface`.  It doesn't work that way.

`ImageReader` is a buffer queue "CPU consumer", which is a fancy way of saying that when you send data to its `Surface`, code running on the CPU can examine the data directly.  Not all surfaces can be handled this way -- the usage flags are set when the surface is created -- so you need to create the `Surface` with `ImageReader#getSurface()` and then pass that to something that wants to send data to a `Surface`.

As the documentation notes, "Several Android media API classes accept Surface objects as targets to render to, including MediaPlayer, MediaCodec, and RenderScript Allocations."

The primary customer for `ImageReader` is the camera, demonstrated in the CTS test you linked to.  It doesn't really work with `MediaCodec` decoders yet because the output formats are different from camera (and some of them are proprietary).

The virtual display test is closer to what you want, because you can direct the output of a virtual display to a `Surface`.  For an app with normal privileges you can only send your own app's output there.  The Android 4.4 "screenrecord" command does something similar.

(If you want to record what you're drawing on a `SurfaceView`, and you're rendering with OpenGL, there are some alternatives demonstrated [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#BreakoutPatch) and [here](https://github.com/google/grafika).)