# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Number of scaling constants does not equal the number of of color or color/alpha components

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, graphics

I am writing aplha composite test app based on this example

```
/* Create an ARGB BufferedImage */
   BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage)image;//ImageIO.read(imageSrc);
   int w = img.getWidth(null);
   int h = img.getHeight(null);
   BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR_PRE);
   Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
   g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

   /* Create a rescale filter op that makes the image 50% opaque */
   float[] scales = { 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f };
   float[] offsets = new float[4];
   RescaleOp rop = new RescaleOp(scales, offsets, null);

   /* Draw the image, applying the filter */
   g2d.drawImage(bi, rop, 0, 0);
```

source link: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html

It works fine with simple images but with photos (jpg etc) I get this exception like:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Number of scaling constants does not
>   equal the number of of color or
>   color/alpha  components

To be more clear... Here is my adapted test code class. This code style throws the exception...

```
public class ImageTest extends JLabel {

    public Image image;
    private BufferedImage bImage;
    ImageObserver imageObserver;
    float[] scales = {1f, 1f, 1f, 1f};
    float[] offsets = new float[4];
    RescaleOp rop;
    int width;
    int height;

    public ImageTest(ImageIcon icon) {

        width = icon.getIconWidth();
        height = icon.getIconHeight();

        this.image = icon.getImage();
        this.imageObserver = icon.getImageObserver();

        //this.bImage=(BufferedImage)image; //previous version (makes exception?)...

        this.bImage = new BufferedImage(
            width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        this.bImage.createGraphics().drawImage(
            this.image, 0, 0, width, height, imageObserver);

        rop = new RescaleOp(scales, offsets, null);
        this.repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(this.bImage, rop, 0, 0);
    }

    public void setRescaleOp(RescaleOp rop) {
        this.rop = rop;
    }
}//class end
```

I am not pretty sure where the exception comes from so I need your advice where to look at?

P.S. I suppose it is the IndexColorModel problem but if so I am not sure how to fix it...

Any useful comment is appreciated :)

Andrew

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Can you post a link to an image that causes the problem?

Comment: Yeah, sure... Here it is http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/576c64ef7b.png

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR_PRE`?

Comment: I want image filter to support alpha composite

Comment: Oh, the code is an example one but I use BufferedImage with no its constructor. Please watch my next post where I describe some details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the example below and the [image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/576c64ef7b.png) you provided, I am unable to reproduce the effect you describe.

I was puzzled that a [`BufferedImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) of `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR_PRE` has a [`ComponentColorModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ComponentColorModel.html), in contrast to the more familiar [`DirectColorModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/DirectColorModel.html), but it's an `IndexColorModel` that cannot be rescaled.

Addendum: Updated code to use `filter()`, as the previous version was incorrectly reusing the [`BufferedImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).

Addendum: In another answer, you said,

> I don't want to create a new `BufferedImage` each time. I want to filter the image on the fly using a `JSlider`.

The [example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/examples/SeeThroughImageApplet.java) you cited does this by creating the `BufferedImage` *once* in the `SeeThroughComponent` constructor and then adjusting just the `RescaleOp` in the slider's change handler. It seems quite responsive.

Addendum: In an edit to your question, you mention that the `IllegalArgumentException` may arise when encountering an image having an [`IndexColorModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/IndexColorModel.html). I am able to reproduce this using, e.g. `TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED`. You may be able to work around such images by trapping the exception and rendering them separately as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658554/using-graphics2d-to-overlay-text-on-a-bufferedimage-and-return-a-bufferedimage/2658663#2658663).

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RescaleOp;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838842 */
public class RescaleOpTest extends JPanel {

    public static final String LINK =
        "http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/576c64ef7b.png";

    public RescaleOpTest() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        Image img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new URL(LINK));
//            img = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
        int w = img.getWidth(null);
        int h = img.getHeight(null);
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
            w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR_PRE);
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();

        /* Create a rescale filter op that makes the image 75% opaque */
        float[] scales = {1f, 1f, 1f, 0.75f};
        float[] offsets = new float[4];
        RescaleOp rop = new RescaleOp(scales, offsets, null);
        bi = rop.filter(bi, null);
        this.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
        this.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)));
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("RescaleOpTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new RescaleOpTest().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about my previous misunderstanding of the question. Please comment if this example does not recapitulate your test case.

Comment: I have just noticed the ImageIcon doc and it says ImageIcon cannot use BufferedImage in its constructor just Image http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html... So I guess I need to repaint here?

Comment: `ImageIcon` is just a convenient way to display the image, and a `BufferedImage` _is_ an `Image`.

Comment: I've elaborated above; the example you cited work well with the image you provided.

Comment: It's greate :) But why mine doesn't then? OK I am going to check it more deeply then and report my results.

Comment: @trashgod I have edited my question... What you think? Do you have the same exception?

Comment: Sorry I overlooked your update previously; I've added more above.

Comment: @trashgod OK. So I have modified some code. PLease watch my question. The image becomes alpha but it seems alpha image makes background visible but its backgroung is black :( What have I missed here?

Comment: I think `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR_PRE` is wrong; `TYPE_INT_ARGB` is more typical.

Comment: @trashgod I edited this emm... the foreground becomes alpha but backround is still black :( Please watch my TestImage code modifications

Comment: I have corrected your `ImageTest` and adapted it to include a scale factor. As it would make a suitable answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864490), I will update my answer there with the results. Please accept this answer, as it explains the `IllegalArgumentException` mentioned in your question.

Comment: Emm, as I was saying, the code in my question is making foreground as transparent but the background is black. That shouldn't be so I need to think it more deeply maybe it is the jpg format which is not supporting the tranparency... I have converted the sample image from jpg to png with my paint the windows editor... So maybe it is the reason of the black image background but still I have to find out more deeply... So I guess the question is not solved totally because the exception is gone, yes, but I cannot get the real JLabel image transparency because of its black background...

Comment: A black image background is usually an incorrectly initialized `BufferedImage`.

Comment: @trashgod  OK, I have fixed it yet :)

Comment: I have updated this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864490/how-to-setsize-of-image-using-rescaleop/5864503#5864503) with a related example.