# How to change brightness of image in JLabel?

Tags: java, swing

I have an image imported in JLabel. Is there any built in function in Java that i can use to change brightness and contrast of that image with a Slider?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try [RescaleOp](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/RescaleOp.html) class (pixel-by-pixel rescaling) methods.

Comment: You can attach a listener to the Slider and call the `filter` method of the RescaleOp class to increase or decrease the contrast of your image, based on the position of the slider.

Comment: +1 for `RescaleOp`. There's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864490/how-to-setsize-of-image-using-rescaleop/5864503#5864503).