# Java Buffered Image RescaleOp Transparency Issue

Tags: java, graphics, transparency, bufferedimage, brightness

I seem to be having an issue where I create a BufferedImage which has transparent pixels like this:

```
BufferedImage buff = new BufferedImage(i.getWidth(null), i.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

and it works fine until I filter it through the RescaleOp to darken it.  When I do this, the image disappears.  Here is my complete code just so you can see how I am setting this up:

```
    BufferedImage buff = new BufferedImage(i.getWidth(null), i.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = buff.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    RescaleOp filter = new RescaleOp(lightlevel, 0f, null);
    buff = filter.filter(buff, null);
```

My question is, how do I fix this so the buffered image will have its pixels darkened without affecting the transparency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [`RescaleOp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/RescaleOp.html#RescaleOp%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20java.awt.RenderingHints%29) that handles *alpha*, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864503/230513), and use the same `lightLevel` for all color components.

Comment: Don't I have the same exact thing there except without the offsets?