# Darkening image using Graphics2D issue in Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics2d, paint

My small Java program is trying to darken a png image. It's working fine on my Mac but when I try to run it on a Windows PC with java 1.7_07 installed but it doesn't show anything at all except an empty JPanel, the image is completely disappeared.

Here is the code:

```
class MapCanvas extends JPanel {
    private Color color;
    RescaleOp op;
    BufferedImage sourceImage, bi;

    public MapCanvas() {
        try {
            sourceImage = ImageIO.read(new File(MAP_FILENAME));

            bi = new BufferedImage(sourceImage.getWidth(), sourceImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

            op = new RescaleOp(.8f, 0, null);
            bi = op.filter(bi, null);

            Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();

            g.drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, 500, 382, null);
            g.dispose();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // set size for the panel
        Dimension size = new Dimension(500, 382);
        this.setBackground(new Color(34, 102, 187));
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setSize(size);
        setLayout(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.drawImage(bi, op, 0, 0);  
    }
}
```

Anyone know why I'm getting this? Many thanks.

Comment: "It doesn't work as expected" - What does it do then, and how is it different from what you expect? Don't just say "it doesn't work" - explain it, otherwise you're just making it hard for people to help you.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've already edited. The problem is the canvas is empty and doesn't show the image.

Comment: For reference, there's a complete example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5864503/230513).

Comment: Have you tried RGB instead of ARGB?

Comment: This may be a silly question, but is your file (referenced by `MAP_FILENAME`) in the same location on your windows machine (as on your mac)?  I personally wasn't able to recreate the problem with the code provided, but I may be missing a configuration...

Comment: `sourceImage = ImageIO.read(new File(MAP_FILENAME));` The map will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource] by the time this is deployed, so the map will only be accessible by `URL` (not `File`).

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, my MAP_FILENAME actually is a physical file on my computer and in the same directory (root directory).That's why it works fine on my Mac.
@eSuarez: I had tried that and the whole image became absolutely dark, i mean black.
Anyway, I fixed it now. Thanks you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't seem to have any issues, BUT, several things jump out at me about this example...

Firstly, I don't see why you've done this...

```
try {
    sourceImage = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/shane/Dropbox/issue453.jpg"));

    bi = new BufferedImage(sourceImage.getWidth(), sourceImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    op = new RescaleOp(.1f, 0, null);
    bi = op.filter(bi, null);

    Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();

    g.drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, 500, 382, null);
    g.dispose();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then done this...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(bi, op, 0, 0);
}
```

You're basically double apply the `RescaleOp`.

It could simply just apply the `RescaleOp` directly to the `sourceImage`...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(sourceImage, op, 0, 0);
}
```

Unless you're concerned about performance, in which case you should simple draw the `bi` without any `BufferedImageOp`

```
g2d.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);
```

Secondly, your example won't compile because you've not defined `g2d` in your `paintComponent` method.  This is either an oversight (which is fine) OR you are caching the `Graphics` object, which is not fine.

`Graphics` objects are stateless, they do not persist between repaints, you should NEVER cache them or rely on `getGraphics`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing out my mistakes. There is some missing code in my question (the Graphics2D g2d - it's just an unassigned variable) so it doesn't compile. Sorry about that.

This is how I fixed it:

```
           `sourceImage = ImageIO.read(new File(MAP_FILENAME));

            bi = new BufferedImage(sourceImage.getWidth(), sourceImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

            float[] scales = { .5f, .5f, .5f, 1f };
            float[] offsets = new float[4];
            op = new RescaleOp(scales, offsets, null);

            Graphics2D g1 = bi.createGraphics();

            g1.drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, 500, 382, null);
            g1.dispose();

            op.filter(sourceImage, bi);`
```

I just use the same value for RGB in the scales array (that's how it supposed to be) then draw the filtered image.

```
            `g2d.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, 500, 382, null);`
```

Cheers