# Creating a flash effect with java swing, or JavaCV

Tags: java, swing, camera

I am working on a photobooth program and would like to create a "Flash" everytime a picture is taken. the only way I have come up with to do this after a bit of research, is to replace the image with an all white image for a moment. However this is not clean especially since I hope to make the the program agnostic to resolution (it is fixed at 720 atm). I have it set up with javacv video feed, using bufferedimages in swing.

I would like to honestly flash the screen, the vid or the GUI. The main goal is to use flash to indicate when the picture was taken.

Answer (score 1):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2124507/230513), you can get a nice effect by varying the image's saturation in [HSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) color space. The example uses a color lookup table with linear variations, but you might experiment with a series of logarithmic decrements from white.

Addendum: To apply this to a `BufferedImage`, use `RescaleOp` on the desired component. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864503/230513) varies the *alpha* component.

Comment: I like the idea, but having trouble combining it with a buffered image. I don't see a clean or easy way to do that in the API. Any advice?

Comment: I've cited a related example above.