# How can I make a BufferedImage "fainter"?

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

I am drawing a Bufferedimage

```
BufferedImage map = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("map.png"));
```

but I would like to either a) put a whiter filter on top, or b) change the alpha value so that it's not as bright. I've tried

```
for (int x = 0; x < map.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < map.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            int tempcolor = map.getRGB(x, y);
            int newalpha = (60 << 24) | (tempcolor & 0x00ffffff);
            map.setRGB(x, y, newalpha);
        }
        }
g.drawImage(map, 0, 0, this);
```

but the image looks exactly like the original. Any ideas?

Comment: Alpha will only allow the lower layer to show through. If there's no lower layer, nothing happens.

Comment: That makes sense. So I can add a white layer behind it and that should fix the problem.

Comment: While probably slower than using `RescaleOp` your original code should work, given you have an image type (`BufferedImage.TYPE_xxx`) that supports alpha, like `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use  **RescaleOp**  because that handles alpha,

```
    RescaleOp rescale = new RescaleOp(1.2f, 15, null);
    rescaleOp.filter(image, image); // Source and destination are the same.
```

refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864490/how-to-setsize-of-image-using-rescaleop/5864503#5864503) also may help you more

one more [link here](http://gihansblog.com/2011/07/10/brightness-control-with-java-buffered-image-class/) for Brightness control