# Java Swing: How to fill a shape with a single image

Tags: java, image, swing

I know that one can use `g2d.setPaint(new TexturePaint(img,rect))` in order to fill a shape with an Image, but the problem is that the shape is tessellated with the image instead of rescaling the single image to the bounding box of the shape in order to fill the whole area.
 The latter is what I want to achieve.

For example, if I have an image of 20x20 and I want to fill an `Ellipse2D` of width = 200 and height = 300, I would like to fill that `Ellipse2D` with a rescaled version of 200x300 of the image instead of tessellating it with the 20x20 image.

Is there a way to achieve this and hopefully in an efficient way?

Comment: So you want know how to rescale an image?

Comment: Probably that would solve my problem, so yes.

Comment: You can resample an image using either of the approaches cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5864503/230513)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
g2d.setPaint(new TexturePaint(img.getScaledInstance(200, 300, 0),rect));
```

I never tried this out before but it seems like it should work.