# Image transformation results in a red image?

Tags: java, image, awt, transform

I am trying to transform an image by flipping it horizontally and resizing it. The problem is that when the transformation is done the picture's colors are all weird, it has gotten this reddish tone. Is it possible to fix this somehow, I think I read somewhere that it might be some bug in the AWT library but I am not sure?

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class LocalImageSizeFlip {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedImage img = null;

    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\picture.jpg"));
        AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1, -1);
        tx.translate(0, -img.getHeight(null));
        AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
        img = op.filter(img, null);
        img = resize(img, 100, 75);
        File newFile = new File("newPicture.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(img, "JPEG", newFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage image, int width, int height) {
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height,
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    g.dispose();
    return resizedImage;
    }   
}
```

Comment: See also [BufferedImage colour change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122964/bufferedimage-colour-change)

Answer (score 6):

Having an image develop a tint usually means the image is being rendered using the wrong colorspace, Adobe RGB vs. sRGB being a perennial favorite.  Try changing TYPE_INT_ARGB to TYPE_INT_RGB in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following type: BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR

Answer (score 0):

If you have any images already converted and those are almost pinkish/reddish.

You can convert those into RGB again.

```
try {
        File folder = new File("photo/old");
        File[] list = folder.listFiles();
        for (File f : list) {
            String url = f.getAbsolutePath();
            String replce1 = url.replace('\\', '/');
            File file = new File(replce1);
            if (file.exists()) {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

                byte[] buff = new byte[fis.available()];
                fis.read(buff);

                BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(file); 
                BufferedImage biOriginal = new BufferedImage(1200, 800,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
                g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, 1200, 800, null);
                g.dispose();

                fis.close();

                FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream("photo/new/"+file.getName());
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(biOriginal, Main.extensionWithotDot, baos2);
                baos2.flush();
                byte[] imageInByte2 = baos2.toByteArray();
                fos2.write(imageInByte2);
                fos2.close();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```