# The image turns mostly red after processing

Tags: java, image-processing

Recently I wrote a method which takes a photo and does a horizontal mirror (also called horizontal flip) which was working fine with all the pictures I tried (until today). Today I tried the following photo and I get the following result. For some reason most of the image color has changed to red.

Original image

[image]

Image After processing

[image]

The original image is a png and the output is jpeg. I'm not sure if that has to do with it. Here is the code which is doing the flipping

```
public BufferedImage flipImageHorizentally(String imagePath) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));

    AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(-1, 1);
    tx.translate(-bufferedImage.getWidth(null), 0);

    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
    bufferedImage = op.filter(bufferedImage, null);

    System.out.println("Flipped the image horizentally!");

    return bufferedImage;
}
```

I then save the `bufferedImage` which is returned using the code below

```
static void SaveImageToDisk(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
    String folderName = "ProcessedImages";
    Common.CreateFolderIfNotExists(folderName);
    try {
        // retrieve image
        File outputfile = new File(folderName + File.separator + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg");
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", outputfile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What is causing the modified image to get red? How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Could it be that the original image is a cmyk jpg? Did you try reading and writing a different format, e.g. an unsophisticated one like bmp?

Comment: You've taken a alpha based image and saved it as a jpg, this is a known issue

Comment: [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962990/image-transformation-results-in-a-red-image) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072312/jpeg-image-color-gets-drastically-changed-after-just-imageio-read-and-imageio) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963685/java-buffered-image-created-with-red-mask)

Comment: The basic solution is to create another `BufferedImage` using `TYPE_RGB` and painting the original image to it and the saving it