# Java Double Buffering -- access backimage

Tags: java, graphics, awt, bufferedimage, doublebuffered

I'm trying to create a java game that will perform image effects (blurring, deforming, etc. on a `BufferedImage`) in real-time in conjunction with a `BufferStrategy`. To do this, I'd like to be able to access the actual backimage (and perform effects on that), and not just the graphics object obtained from `strategy.getDrawGraphics()`. After searching online *and* through the `awt` source, I haven't been able to find where that image actually is, or how to access it. Does anybody know? Should I just use my own bufferedimage and draw to that, then blit it to the backimage `Graphics`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The actual storage is specified in the direct know subclasses, `Component.BltBufferStrategy` and `Component.FlipBufferStrategy`; it is hidden intentionally as an implementation detail. `JPanel` is double buffered by default. Simply update your `BufferedImage` and render it, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864503/230513) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10208380/230513).