# Changing the min and max value of JSlider depanding on condition

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jslider, affinetransform

I'm creating a Swing GUI in Netbeans. The purpose of this GUI is to open an (buffered)image (in a JLabel as icon) and apply Affine transforms on it. Now there are 4 transforms that I'm doing as follows.

[image]

Now, each transform requires two sliders to change the X and Y value, except that of rotate, which will require only one. I did it this way since its much better than having to do four tabs for all 4 types of transforms. Also I want it to be such that , for example, if an image is rotated, the same rotated image can be sheared by selecting shear from the Drop down list.

The problem is (are):
How do i repaint the label icon and apply different transform on the same repainted image?
Also, how do i change the minimum and maximum value of JSlider depanding on the effect selected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should store originally loaded BufferedImage, and create its copy - that way you won't "destroy" it.

As for the changing value there are methods setMaximum and setMinimum - add listener to list, as stated in [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) and modify the values.

Comment: Yes, as you're supposed to store it somewhere ;)

Comment: You could define a model that has the original buffer and a list of effects which can be used to produce to then return the "resulting" image.  This would allow the ability to change the order of the effects and allow the views to decide how to react it...IMHO

Comment: See also the examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5864503/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10208380/230513).

Answer (score 4):

As a concrete example of @Daniel's answer, the article [*Image processing with Java 2D*](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-1998/jw-09-media.html) describes the program [`ImageDicer`](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-09-1998/media/ImageDicer.java). It constructs a `TreeMap<String, BufferedImageOp>` each of which may be selected from a `JComboBox` and applied to a `BufferedImage`.

See also related examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864503/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10208380/230513).