# java drawstring directly image

Tags: java, image, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Graphics2D to overlay text on a BufferedImage and return a BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658554/using-graphics2d-to-overlay-text-on-a-bufferedimage-and-return-a-bufferedimage)

My Question is how to draw a String permanently to an image.

When I draw the String and then refresh the image the String is gone on the display.

Comment: what exactly is your context? Web application ? JFrame .... ?

Comment: I agree with @MaVRoSCy. Your question is unanswerable as written. Please provide us with more information.

Comment: Oh, Im sorry about this. Im using Java Swing and a JFrame. Basically there are two Graphics objects. The first draws different stuff to an image and the second one draws the whole image on a JPanel in the JFrame. If more information is needed I will of course provide it.

Comment: Perhaps like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2658663/230513)?

Comment: @trashgod: Yes it seems to be the same method as Andrew Thompson described. Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ..how to draw a String permanently to an image.

If you mean a `BufferedImage` then it is simple.

1. Get a [`Graphics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getGraphics%28%29) or [`Graphics2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics%28%29) instance from the image.
2. Draw the string to it.
3. Dispose of the graphics object.

The job is done.  To display the image, add it to a label.

If you have an `Image` instance as opposed to a `BufferedImage` instance, create a buffered image as large as the original image, then paint it to the graphics instance before step 2. (draw the string) above.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the text always show on top of the image, place your `drawString` call inside `paint(Graphics g)`

It would be helpful if you posted some of your code, but I think you are probably calling drawString from the wrong place. Now if you also want to save the image with the text on top, that is another matter. I would probably use `javax.imageio.ImageIO.write` for that.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time! I know about this solution as a workaround. I thought there might be an efficient solution modifying the image directly instead of just drawing the String again and again but it seems there isnt. Still thanks!

Comment: You can modify the image directly. Look at the methods in `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` and you will notice you can call getGraphics() or createGraphics() If you store your image as BufferedImage you can modify it (adding text) through the graphics context.