# Issue regarding dynamically loading Images in loop using Java Swing

Tags: java, image, swing

```
public String[] imagesArray = {Images.firstImage, Images.secondImage};

String imagesPath = "/testproject/images/";
 for(int i = 0; i<imagesArray.length; i++) {
    URL imageURL = this.getClass().getResource(imagesPath+imagesArray[i]);
    ImageIcon orignalImageIcon = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
    Image newImage = orignalImageIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 90, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon newImageIcon = new ImageIcon(newImage);

    JButton receiptButton = new JButton(newImageIcon);
    receiptButton.setBorder((new EmptyBorder(0,0,0,0)));
    toolBar.add(receiptButton);
    add(toolBar);
    }
```

Images not shown in my design layout?

Comment: In above question "Images.firstImage" , Images is a class having static member name 'firstImage' whose value is "print.png"

Comment: `receiptButton.setBorder((new EmptyBorder(0,0,0,0)));`  ...hmmm.  Try the `setBorderPainted()` method.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is most likely the asynchronous loading nature of using an `ImageIcon` to load the original images.

If that is the problem:

1. There is an easy way to test it.  Add the `orignalImageIcon` to the button and see if they all appear.
2. There is an easy way to fix it.  Load the images using `ImageIO.read(URL)` - a method that will block until the image is completely loaded.

Comment: Can you give me an example how i would load images using ImagesIO.read(URL) ?

Comment: @FaizanAhmed: Here's one [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2658663/230513) and another [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6296381/230513). +1, btw.