# Add Dynamically loading images using for loop in JToolBar

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, imageicon, jtoolbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Issue regarding dynamically loading Images in loop using Java Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269567/issue-regarding-dynamically-loading-images-in-loop-using-java-swing)

Can any one tell how I would add images dynamically using for loop in JToolBar. I tried a lot but it didn't work for dynamic loading of images. I want to create ToolBar where I load images in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JToolBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) is particularly well adapted to adding `JButton` instances each having a distinct `Icon`, so I would advocate using [`ImageIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html). Complete examples maybe found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html#eg), and more were cited in comments to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12269926/230513) to your previous question.