# Best manner to place 'markers' on an ImageIcon Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I have a Java swing application where I've created an `ImageIcon` with a picture and displayed it to a screen. I did that by loading a URL as an `ImageIcon` and placing it in the Java Swing window as a label.

Now I need to place 'markers' on the image with other images.
In context: Place a picture of an eye on someones face over their eye.

I'd appreciate anyone who can point my in the right direction or give me some SSCCE code to work from.

What is the best manner to place 'markers' on an `ImageIcon` Java Swing?

Comment: Using `ImageIO` to load your images, this gives you a `BufferedImage`.  This is much easier to draw in.  If you can't, you will need to paint the `ImageIcon` to a `BufferedImage`, paint you marks and then wrap it back into a new `ImageIcon`

Comment: Get the `Graphcs` (or better, the `Graphics2D`) of the main `BufferedImage` and draw the marker images onto it at appropriate size and location.  Check the docs for details and get back to us when *you* can post an SSCCE of *your* best attempt (is what I recommend).

Comment: Thanks guys, will start researching how to use those tools. Any chance either of you have a basic sort of SSCCE I can use to get started?

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2658663/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic concept is, you need a temporary image onto which you can paint the master/base image and the marker.

1. Create a new `BufferedImage`.  This would typically be the same size as the master image, but doesn't have to be.
2. Paint the master image onto `BufferedImage`
3. Paint the marker onto the `BufferedImage`
4. Create a new `ImageIcon` using the `BufferedImage`
5. Apply the `ImageIcon` to the label...

[image][image][image]

```
public class PaintIcon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PaintIcon();
    }

    public PaintIcon() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new PaintPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class PaintPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;
        private int state = 0;

        private BufferedImage disk;
        private BufferedImage play;
        private BufferedImage pause;
        private BufferedImage stop;

        public PaintPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add((label = new JLabel()));

            try {
                disk = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/cd.png"));
                play = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/media_play.png"));
                pause = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/media_pause.png"));
                stop = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/media_stop.png"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            updateState();

            label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    state++;
                    if (state > 2) {
                        state = 0;
                    }
                    updateState();
                }
            });
        }

        protected void updateState() {
            BufferedImage base = new BufferedImage(disk.getWidth(), disk.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = base.createGraphics();
            g2d.drawImage(disk, 0, 0, this);
            BufferedImage marker = null;
            switch (state) {
                case 0:
                    marker = stop;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    marker = play;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    marker = pause;
                    break;
            }
            int x = disk.getWidth() - marker.getWidth();
            int y = disk.getHeight() - marker.getHeight();
            g2d.drawImage(marker, x, y, this);
            g2d.dispose();

            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(base));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I really appreciate your response. I just tried to implement your code however I keep getting errors. I even went and put some some png files into the src and ensured the naming was the same:

errors I got:`code`
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
 at PaintIcon$PaintPane.<init>(PaintIcon.java:59)
 at PaintIcon$1.run(PaintIcon.java:35)`code`

Comment: Basically the error is telling you (in a round about way) that the resource you are trying to load can't be found.

Comment: Strange, I just got a bunch of .png files and named them exactly what you had cd, media_pause, media_stop and media_play

Comment: If you're running Eclipse, you may need to build and Jar the project

Comment: Running Netbeans but I will try that! =]

Comment: Built the example in Netbeans. Make sure the images are in the `default` package of the project.

Comment: Many thanks, it compiles however it just displays a static image, there seems no way of placing one image on to of another or anything?

Comment: Try clicking the icon.  It has a mouse listener that will switch the between the different states ;)