# Overlay images Java

Tags: java, image, swing, awt, overlay

I'm trying to overlay a background picture with a .png sample, and I don't know how it works.
I tried to create 2 JPanels, but didn't find out how to overlay them, then I tried to create 2 JLabels and once again, they just stay separated.

Have you any idea ?
Thanks !

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean _"overlay"_? Please explain more clearly and also show us your attempt and where you're having problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one jPanel.Override paint or paintComponent  method and draw your picture with graphic object.

```
    public class MyCustomPanel extends JPanel{

    private Image img;

    public MyCustomPanel(// use constructor to get img or load it directly from below){
     //load image
    } 

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            // Draws the img to the BackgroundPanel.
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        }


}
```

Then you can go to your main class and use this JPanel

```
MyCustomPanel mcp=new MyCustomPanel(//img path);
mcp.add(new JLabel("Hello"),BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(mcp),BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

//etc

I hope you understand

Next time post some code if you want to have answr faster and more complex/better suited for your case.

Comment: `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);` should be `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);`.  Every [`Component`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) **is an** [`ImageObserver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ImageObserver.html), so we might as well use it as such.

Comment: Oh, plus the answer breaks the painting chain.  It should override `paintComponent`, and immediately call the `super` method..

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2658663/230513).

Comment: Thank you guys for pointing out mistakes !:) fixed .Wasnt sure which one shoud be called at first trashgod thx for explaining:).Im glad that i learn even from my answers :D