# Create Multi-Page Tiff with Java

Tags: java, tiff, javax.imageio, twelvemonkeys

I'm interested in taking a tif image and adding a layer to it that contains text with Java, preferably with the Twelve Monkeys image library if possible.

I can tweak the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658554/using-graphics2d-to-overlay-text-on-a-bufferedimage-and-return-a-bufferedimage/2658663#2658663) to either add text to a tif or create a new tif of the same size with only text, but not save them as a multi-page tif. For example:

```
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ImageUtil {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    BufferedImage src = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/main.tif"));
    BufferedImage text = createTextLayer(src);
    BufferedImage[] images = new BufferedImage[]{src, text};
    createMultiPage(images);

}

private static BufferedImage createTextLayer(BufferedImage src) {
    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(
            w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

    g2d.setPaint(Color.red);
    g2d.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 200));
    String s = "Hello, world!";
    FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
    int x = img.getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(s) - 5;
    int y = fm.getHeight() * 5;
    g2d.drawString(s, x, y);
    g2d.dispose();
    return img;
}

private static void createMultiPage(BufferedImage[] images) throws IOException {

    File tempFile = new File("/new/file/path.tif");
    //I also tried passing in stream var below to the try, but also receive java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported write variant!
    //OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);

    // Obtain a TIFF writer
    ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIFF").next();

    try (ImageOutputStream output = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(tempFile)) {
        writer.setOutput(output);

        ImageWriteParam params = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
        params.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        params.setCompressionType("None");

        //error here: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported write variant!
        writer.prepareWriteSequence(null);

        for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
            writer.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(images[i], null, null), params);
        }

        // We're done
        writer.endWriteSequence();
    }

}
}
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>imageio-tiff</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

How can I create a multi-page tif from an image and the generated text-image?

I was able to get the following code to run for jpgs, but jpgs don't have layers.

```
public static void testWriteSequence() throws IOException {
    BufferedImage[] images = new BufferedImage[] {
            new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB),
            new BufferedImage(110, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB),
            new BufferedImage(120, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB),
            new BufferedImage(130, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
    };

    Color[] colors = {Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.ORANGE};

    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        BufferedImage image = images[i];
        Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
        try {
            g2d.setColor(colors[i]);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        }
        finally {
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    //ImageWriter writer = createImageWriter();
    ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("JPEG").next();

    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (ImageOutputStream output = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(buffer)) {
        writer.setOutput(output);

        ImageWriteParam params = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
        params.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);

        writer.prepareWriteSequence(null);

        params.setCompressionType("JPEG");
        writer.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(images[0], null, null), params);

        params.setCompressionType("JPEG");
        writer.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(images[1], null, null), params);

        params.setCompressionType("JPEG");
        writer.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(images[2], null, null), params);

        params.setCompressionType("JPEG");
        writer.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(images[3], null, null), params);

        writer.endWriteSequence();

        File tempFile = new File("/path/to/new/file.jpg");
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);

        buffer.writeTo(out);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: if I put "Create Multi-Page Tiff with Java " on the search here will give me the answer; is that hard labor??

Comment: @gpasch Care to share a link so I can evaluate what you are seeing, or are you just the StackOverflow police?

Comment: @gpasch If you think this question is already answered, you should vote to close and mark it as a duplicate. It may cost you more than a random comment and a down vote, but in return it actually helps the community.

Comment: @jonD02 The problem with your updated code is that you use `ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(...)` twice... First passing the file (correct), then the second passing an `ImageOutputStream` (doesn't work, and returns `null`). My code didn't do that. If you remove the `stream` variable, and instead pass `tempFile` inside the `try` you'll be good.

Comment: @haraldK Thanks for the update. I tried using an OutputStream and passing the tempFile into the try and still no luck, receiving UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported write variant!. I updated my post with the current code. I also added a jpg example to the end of the post that I modified from the TwelveMonkeys testWriteSequence method which I was able to run successfully, but I can't get it to work for tifs.

Comment: @haraldK updating to 3.3.1 solved the issue, thanks!

Comment: @haraldK related question, is there a way to generate the tif pages so Photoshop will treat them as layers?

Comment: @haraldK Looking at the layered tif in a text editor I'm not seeing a tag, so must be in the encrypted data. I made a new [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41110630/create-layered-tif-with-java-for-use-in-photoshop), thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write multi-page images (in formats that supports it, like TIFF), using the standard `ImageIO` API. Now that Java ImageIO comes with a TIFF plugin bundled, starting from Java 9, the below should just work, with no extra dependencies. For Java 8 and earlier, you still need a TIFF plugin, like JAI or TwelveMonkeys as mentioned.

See for example the [TIFFImageWriterTest.testWriteSequence](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/imageio/imageio-tiff/src/test/java/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/plugins/tiff/TIFFImageWriterTest.java#L296) method from the TwelveMonkeys ImageIO project's test cases, for an example of how to do it.

The important part:

```
BufferedImage[] images = ...
OutputStream stream = ... // May also use File here, as output

// Obtain a TIFF writer
ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIFF").next();

try (ImageOutputStream output = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(stream)) {
    writer.setOutput(output);

    ImageWriteParam params = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    params.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);

    // Compression: None, PackBits, ZLib, Deflate, LZW, JPEG and CCITT variants allowed
    // (different plugins may use a different set of compression type names)
    params.setCompressionType("Deflate");

    writer.prepareWriteSequence(null);

    for (BufferedImage image : images) {
        writer.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(image, null, null), params);
    }

    // We're done
    writer.endWriteSequence();
}

writer.dispose();
```

Comment: thanks for the response, appreciate it! I've been trying the code in various ways, but I'm receiving an IllegalStateException: getOutput() == null exception at writer.prepareWriteSequence. I updated my code above to where I'm at after checking your link and searching for a solution. Do you know what is missing from my example above? Thanks.

Comment: @jonD02 You made a small mistake, I explained in a comment to your question. Note that `stream` in my code is a `java.io.OutputStream`, but in your code it is a `javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream`, which is a different thing, and is the reason you get the exception.