# Saving multi layer TIFF with python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, photoshop, tiff, layer

I'm trying to find a way to stack multiple images into layers of a TIFF image so that Photoshop will recognise those images as separate layers in Python. 
I tried creating multiple pages TIFF as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540119/how-to-create-a-multiple-frame-image-using-python-pil) But Photoshop only recognises one layer. 
Also Tried using this code, but also got only one layer

```
import glob
from PIL import Image
FRAMES = [] 
FIRST_SIZE = None 
OUT_NAME = "test.tiff" 
filelist = glob.glob("photos/*") 
for i in filelist:
    img = Image.open(i)
    FRAMES.append(img)
FRAMES[0].save(OUT_NAME, save_all=True, append_images=FRAMES)
```

Please help me.

Comment: Pages and layers are two different things. Unless things have changed with the last few versions, Photoshop does not support multi-page TIFF files but it does support layered TIFFs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port and finish [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51653003/819417) or [control Photoshop from Python](https://forums.adobe.com/message/10528918#10528918):

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

psApp = Dispatch("Photoshop.Application")
psApp.Open(r"C:\Users\Kim-DEV\psd_env\test1.psd") 
doc = psApp.ActiveDocument
layerRef = doc.ArtLayers.Add()

psTextLayer = 2  # from enum PsLayerKind
layerRef.Kind = psTextLayer

textItem = layerRef.TextItem
textItem.Contents = "HELLO WORLD!"
textItem.Position = (120, 120)
```

Then `doc.Save()` or [export to a different format](http://techarttiki.blogspot.com/2008/08/photoshop-scripting-with-python.html).