# How to convert pdf file in to multipagetiff images using pdfBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

```
document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfFilename));
PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
int pageCounter = 0;

for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {

    BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageCounter, 300, ImageType.RGB);
    ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, pdfFilename + "-" + (pageCounter++) + ".tif", 300);

}
```

Instead of creating multiple single image how to create multipage image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41038987/984823

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973354/converting-pdf-to-multipage-tiff-group-4/31974376#31974376