# How to generate bar code using google zxing library in java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, barcode, barcode-scanner

I want to generate bar code with text size 16 characters. Now I'm using google zxing library for generating bar code.

It is generating the bar code with character size of 16 but it will not print the entered data below the bar code.

```
String text = "SKCN_031123_0003";

MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();

int width = 100;

int height = 100;

BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, height, width);

MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(bitMatrix, "png", new FileOutputStream(new File("E:/Projects/visa-admin/userdocs/barcode.png")));
```

This code generates bar code like:

[Need to print the text below the bar code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObQJZ.png)

I'm trying to find solution but they are all related to CODE_13 and UPCAWriter().

I've trying to resolve it so long but I won't found anything useful.

Also, is there any other way to generate barcode more than 16 characters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to a previous SO question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658554/using-graphics2d-to-overlay-text-on-a-bufferedimage-and-return-a-bufferedimage/2658663#2658663) you'll have to print your text by yourself via Graphics2D (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658554/using-graphics2d-to-overlay-text-on-a-bufferedimage-and-return-a-bufferedimage/2658663#2658663)